# Runtime stack for Azure Function App vs Azure Web App services

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am curious to know the intent behind providing the Function App service only with one option i.e. **.Net** option(restricting to .Net) as **Runtime stack** where as Web App service with more variant options as (.Net/Net6 Early Access/.NEt Core/ASP.NET) to choose as **Runtime stack**.

Answer (score 1):

Functions does support multiple languages - [Azure Functions runtime versions overview | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages)

The only difference why their is fewer selection compare to web-app, this is because of how Functions work and how the functions runtime works - [Azure/azure-functions-host: The host/runtime that powers Azure Functions (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host)

While that would be a much bigger answer if we were to talk about the design of the runtime, the good news is that any language can be used by leveraging custom handlers - [Azure Functions custom handlers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers)

Comment: Could you please accept the answer as solution, If above mentioned answer helped you . This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.